# Twitter-Bootstrap in vid. player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a custom media player, but buttons and progress bar isn't doing a things the should, I'm using Bootstrap with Bootswatch theme (Paper), here is a [Template](https://jsfiddle.net/nydjakhz/)

Whats's wrong? Please help!

Thanks!

Sorry for my English...

```html
<div id='media-player'>
      <video id='media-video' controls>
        <source src="http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/763_sammyJSIntro/trailer_test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/763_sammyJSIntro/trailer_test.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      </video>
      <div id='media-controls'>
        <button id='play-pause-button' class="btn btn-default play" id="play" title="play" onclick='togglePlayPause();'>play</button>
        <div class="progress">
          <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar" min='0' max='100' value='0'>0% played</div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="fullScreen" title="FullScreen Toggle"> FS </button>
      </div>
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  initialiseMediaPlayer();
}, false);
var mediaPlayer;

function initialiseMediaPlayer() {
  mediaPlayer = document.getElementById('media-video');
  mediaPlayer.controls = false;
}

function togglePlayPause() {
  var btn = document.getElementById('play-pause-button');
  if (mediaPlayer.paused || mediaPlayer.ended) {
    btn.title = 'pause';
    btn.innerHTML = 'pause';
    btn.className = 'btn btn-default play';
    mediaPlayer.play();
  } else {
    btn.title = 'play';
    btn.innerHTML = 'play';
    btn.className = 'btn btn-default play';
    mediaPlayer.pause();
  }
}
mediaPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgressBar, false);

function updateProgressBar() {
  var progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
  var percentage = Math.floor((100 / mediaPlayer.duration) * mediaPlayer.currentTime);
  progressBar.value = percentage;
  progressBar.innerHTML = percentage + '% played';
}
```

Comment: Not working? Please be a bit more specific on what is not working please.

Comment: All of the buttons and the progress bar isn't working, You can see it on the JSfiddle

Comment: The buttons and the progress bar in the fiddle you provided works fine for me here Egor. Can you try clearing your cache and checking it again. Also, check your browser console if you're getting any errors.

Comment: there's a problem with bootstrap buttons and bs progress bar(watch them below the video container)